# Using selenium-webdriver for parsing (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, parsing, selenium-webdriver, mechanize

Previously I used mechanize for parsing, but now I'm parsing website that uses javscript and mechanize doesn't support it, so I took selenium. I have to take information about companies from this website but I can get the information only after click on javascript link. I did it with selenium, my parser clicks on javascript, then collects information and here appear problems. As you understand I need to save collected information to the database and I can do this properly only if  information will be stored in the variables (e.g. address=.., phone=.., email=.., etc). I select necessary information with SelectorGadget and selenium collects information (`driver.find_element(:css, ..)`, but the information about all the companies is located in a single selector  (`.p2 div`) 
and I can not save the location as a single variable, the phone in the other variable, etc. So my question - is it possible to divide this text and save in the variables?

Photos that illustrate the process:

i.imgur.com/J5dcGZD.png

i.imgur.com/MaBWICZ.png

i.imgur.com/ZDNXhLt.png

Photo with part of html:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMm2d.png

[Here](http://www.ypag.ru/cat/komp249/page0.html) is an example page of this site. The site is in Russian so translate it through Google translator

The parser itself (save a bunch of text from each company to the contacts variable):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://www.ypag.ru/cat/komp249/page3880.html"


loop do
driver.find_elements(:css, ".p2 div a").each {|link| link.click}
driver.find_elements(:css, ".p3 a, .firm , .p2 div").each {
|n,r,c|
name = n
region = r
contacts = c

print name.text.center(100)
puts region
puts contacts

}
link = driver.find_element(:xpath, "/html/body/table[5]/tbody/tr/td/a[2]" )[:href]
break if link == "http://www.ypag.ru/cat/komp249/page3780.html"
driver.get "#{link}"
end
```

Comment: `driver.find_elements(:css, ".p3 a, .firm , .p2 div").each {
|n,r,c|` is not valid.. Can you give a part of the HTML and from that HTML what data you want to have,.. That will be a nice question..

Comment: I have added pictures that show show the process

Comment: Humm Great! now just from that sample.. just put the three information you want in three variables..I am an Indian..so that language is tough for me.. :)

Comment: Information may be more(4 or 5)

Comment: where is `name`,`region` and `contact` in the html?

Comment: Probably you didn't understand me:) The point is that I can't select with SelectorGadget nor address, nor phone so that css selector for them worked on all pages and all companies. If I incorrectly understood you please explain more